# is there a way to pre-start threads on sphinxsearch

Tags: multithreading, sphinx

we have large sphinx distributed cluster,
single frontend distributed index, with 3 backend servers each with small local distributed index.

from time to time, during high traffic spikes, on backend servers we see load average as high as 80.

at the same time, I can see sphinx hawe spawn 150 - 200 threads, that quickly drops to say 50 and then they go back to 150 - 200, then again back down to 50 and so on.

Is there a way to "prefork" / prestart those threads? e.g. something like apache's MinSpareServers.

In fact we use dedicated hardware, so we will not have problem, if sphinx use more memory when is idle.

on the backend servers, we are using realtime index and we can no swith to prefork model.

we have full root access so we can tweak linux system settings too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in 2.3 workers=thread_pool creates at start a fixed number of working threads, which is either 1.5*detected cores or max_children directive. The threads are put under a pool. The incoming connections are handled by separate thread(s), which allocates the queries to the working pool. The old workers=threads creates a thread for every query.